# Compare a column between 2 csvs and merge data into one csv

Tags: python

I am trying to print out a csv file by comparing a column between two csv files:
CSV1:

```
network, geoname
1.0.0.0/24, 123456
2.0.0.0/24, 76890
.....
```

CSV2:

```
geoname, country_code, country
123456, XX, ABC
....
....
```

I want to compare the geoname column between csv 1 & 2 and map the network section according to the geoname and associated country and country code.

Final CSV:

```
network, geoname, country code, country
1.0.0.0/24,123456, XX, ABC
```

NB: csv1 contains duplicate geonames as well while csv2 maps the geonames to the country.

I am trying to map the network section in csv1 using the geonames and get the associated country and code in my final csv.

The current problem i am facing is that the code will only run until the 2nd CSV file finishes and hence, I am not able to map things properly.

```
#script for making GeipCountrywhois csv for input to zmap

from asyncore import write
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
indir=os.environ['HOME']+'/code/surveys/mmdb/GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20220308/'
v4file=indir+'GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv'
localefile = indir+'GeoLite2-Country-Locations-en.csv'
outfile = indir+'GeoIPCountryWhois.csv'

data = []
data2 = []
data3 = []

with open(v4file, "r") as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
of = open(outfile, "w")
writer = csv.writer(of)
for row in reader:
    ip_cidr = row[0]
    geoname =row[1]
    data = [ip_cidr, geoname]
    #print(data)

    with open(localefile, "r") as file:
        reader2 = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader2:
        geoname_en = row[0]
        cc = row[4]
        country = row[5]
        data2 = [geoname, cc, country]
        #print(data2)

        if(data[1] == data2[0]):
            data3 = [ip_cidr, geoname, cc, country]
            writer.writerow(data3)
            print(data3)
```

Comment: you haven't posted any code. could you share your code?

Comment: What data structure are you reading your csv into? `pandas.DataFrames` or something else? Please include the code you've tried so far and specify where exactly you are getting stuck.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using python pandas or not... I can put a `pandas` solution for you.

At first install pandas in your python environment if `pandas` is not installed in your system before. You can using pandas using the following command -

```sh
python -m pip install pandas
```

Then try this code block -

```py
import pandas as pd

# load csv1, assume that its name is network.csv
network = pd.read_csv('network.csv')

# Then load csv2, assume that its name is geonames.csv
geo = pd.read_csv('geonames.csv') 

# create a geo mapper
final_csv = network.merge(geo, how='left', on='geoname')

# save result as csv
final_csv.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)
```